# How can i read mp3 tags c#, windows 8 metro ap

Tags: c#, windows-8

i`m writing simple metro style app in c#. Now i have problem accessing files after picking them with filepicker. I got file access error in TagLib.File.Create(fileo.Path).

```
    var picker = new FileOpenPicker();
    picker.FileTypeFilter.Add(".mp3");
    var file = await picker.PickMultipleFilesAsync();
foreach (StorageFile fileo in file)
    {
     TagLib.File mp3 = TagLib.File.Create(fileo.Path);
     string pikkus = mp3.Properties.Duration.ToString();
    }
```

Comment: Do you have access rights to read the files?

Comment: In windows 8 all metro apps runs in sandbox. I can only access them when i use filepicker. One way is using stream var stream = await fileo.OpenAsync(Windows.Storage.FileAccessMode.ReadWrite), but taglib wont accept stream input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you can read the mp3 tags buy Get the MusicPropertes with the file.

```
MusicProperties musicProp = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
```

Answer (score 2):

I found a solution here [How to: Get IDE Tags of a file](http://ks-developer.com/tutorials/read_mp3tags.html)

Read Mp3 Tags:

```
try
{
var file = await StorageFile.GetFileFromPathAsync(path);
MusicProperties musicProperties = await file.Properties.GetMusicPropertiesAsync();
}
catch(Exception e){
//Error Message here
}
```

Show Mp3 Tags:

```
string title = musicProperties.Title;
string artist = musicProperties.Artist;
string album = musicProperties.Album;
```